# How to apply Hypothesis test on time series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I am working on a project that is related to Wikipedia's revision history. I have around 10 time-series and each one represents how the relative frequency of positive words changes over time.

I need to test the hypothesis, that the batch of females samples have larger relative frequencies than the batch of males samples. But, this I want to hold over time.
I have tried ANOVA, but I am not sure if it is the proper way and how to interpret the results, because I am testing only one value which is the average over time.

What is the proper way to apply hypothesis tests on time series data?

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17881/hypothesis-testing-and-significance-for-time-series

Comment: Hey, thank you for pointing this but I am not sure that it is what I want.